# Javascript's removeEventListener not working

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, publish-subscribe

I have tried some solutions already such as that callback functions are both the same. I still can't get it to work.

removeClickEventHandler function inside view module is not working. Event listener is applied from controller. I abstracted some code from the view module but I left controller module as it is.

Controller code:

```
import navigationView from "./view/navView.js";
import ticTacToeView from "./view/ticTacToeView.js";
import ticTacModule from "./modules/ticTacModule.js";

class Controller {
      constructor() {
        navigationView.addHoverEventHandlers(navigationView.hoverFunction);
        navigationView.addClickHandler(this.showContent.bind(this));
      }
    
      showContent() {
        ticTacToeView.renderContent(navigationView.clickedContent);
        ticTacToeView.addClickEventHandler(this.ticTacToeControl.bind(this));
        ticTacToeView.addHoverHandler(ticTacToeView.hoverFunction);
      }
    
      ticTacToeControl(clickedBox) {
        if (ticTacToeView.checkIfBoxEmpty(clickedBox)) {
          ticTacToeView.createMark(clickedBox, ticTacModule.activePlayer);
          ticTacModule.updateBoardState(clickedBox);
          ticTacModule.changeActivePlayer();
          ticTacToeView.highlightActivePlayer(ticTacModule.activePlayer);
          ticTacModule.checkForWinner();
          if (ticTacModule.winner) {
            ticTacToeView.renderWinner(ticTacModule.winner);
            ticTacToeView.removeClickEventHandler(this.ticTacToeControl);
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

This is view module code:

```
import View from "./View.js";

class TicTacToeView extends View {

  addClickEventHandler(fn) {
    const ticTacContainer = document.querySelector(".tic-tac-toe");
    ticTacContainer.addEventListener("click", fn, true);
  }

  removeClickEventHandler(fn) {
    const ticTacContainer = document.querySelector(".tic-tac-toe");
    ticTacContainer.removeEventListener("click", fn, true);
  }
}
export default new TicTacToeView();
```

Comment: It's likely your function reference is changing (are you sure `this.ticTacToeControl` is the same reference?) or the element being selected with `querySelector` is different (could there be multiple elements with that class on the page?).

Comment: Seems that either the element reference or the function reference is changing between calls. An easy fix is to return a `removeListener` function from the `addListener` function ensuring (via closure) that the same function and element are bieng accessed.

Comment: Both functions work for me: https://jsfiddle.net/dqfw4hcm/1/ Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @pilchard Is it necessary? Would it change anything? My example shows that the provided code works and the function reference changes. We can't help without more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bind` creates a new function with a new reference. `this.ticTacToeControl` and `this.ticTacToeControl.bind(this)` are two different functions with two different references. Store the function reference in a variable and use it to remove the event listener.

```
class Controller {
  constructor() {
    navigationView.addHoverEventHandlers(navigationView.hoverFunction);
    navigationView.addClickHandler(this.showContent.bind(this));
  }

  showContent() {
    ticTacToeView.renderContent(navigationView.clickedContent);
    this.handler = this.ticTacToeControl.bind(this);
    ticTacToeView.addClickEventHandler(this.handler);
    ticTacToeView.addHoverHandler(ticTacToeView.hoverFunction);
  }

  ticTacToeControl(clickedBox) {
    if (ticTacToeView.checkIfBoxEmpty(clickedBox)) {
      ticTacToeView.createMark(clickedBox, ticTacModule.activePlayer);
      ticTacModule.updateBoardState(clickedBox);
      ticTacModule.changeActivePlayer();
      ticTacToeView.highlightActivePlayer(ticTacModule.activePlayer);
      ticTacModule.checkForWinner();
      if (ticTacModule.winner) {
        ticTacToeView.renderWinner(ticTacModule.winner);
        ticTacToeView.removeClickEventHandler(this.handler);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It works now. I didn't realize bind creates a new function. Very new to the code and after a few hours of frustration I didn't even bother to make an abstracted example. Still, thank you again for finding the solution.